# Regex returns value even when it doesn't match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regex like this:

```
string.match(/((?:website.com\/video\/)([\d]+))/);
```

When the string is supposed to match, everything is fine, however it always returns *something* even if the string is "facebook.com", I still get back "facebook.com", how can I make it return null?

Comment: Seeing a bit more code would help. Also, you should escape the period and you can drop the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine, but strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) so I'm guessing you're not returning the result but just expecting the original string to change :

```
string = string.match(/((?:website.com\/video\/)([\d]+))/);
```

will return `null` if it does not match.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xEMVb/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably late but here's my 50c

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // var string = 'website.com/video/1'; // uncomment to test
        var string = 'facebook.com';
        if (string.match(/((?:website.com\/video\/)([\d]+))/)) {
            $("p").html(string);
        } else {
            $("p").html("No match");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Fiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/FgqkR/)